# how to "active: running" docker in ubuntu when the status result is "Active: failed (Result: exit-code)"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

after the migration of the cloud server between two data-center, my docker doesn't work correctly. I can't see my containers and images. and i receive error below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-servername-server:~$ sudo docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

and when i checked the status of the docker by "systemctl status docker" I received "active: failed" error.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-gardooon-server:~$ sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-09-10 16:29:10 UTC; 2 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 35714 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 10 16:29:08 ubuntu-gardooon-server systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, statu>
Sep 10 16:29:08 ubuntu-gardooon-server systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 10 16:29:08 ubuntu-gardooon-server systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 10 16:29:10 ubuntu-gardooon-server systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter >
Sep 10 16:29:10 ubuntu-gardooon-server systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 10 16:29:10 ubuntu-gardooon-server systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 10 16:29:10 ubuntu-gardooon-server systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 10 16:29:10 ubuntu-gardooon-server systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

docker and docker-compose are installed on my server and the versions of them are:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-gardooon-server:~$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2
ubuntu@ubuntu-gardooon-server:~$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

after i saw these errors i trying to check the docker folder in /var/lib/ on ubuntu 20.04 and i couldn't open it. so after some tries i deleted the folder by mistake.
now please help me to find out how i can run my docker and if possible recover my containers and images? and if not, please let me know how i can rebuild my docker?
Thank you
.........................
I tried to reinstall the docker. with command (apt --reinstall install docke) but i received message below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-gardooon-server:~$ sudo apt install docker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
docker is already the newest version (1.5-2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1 libgd3 libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libtiff5 libwebp6 libxpm4
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 122 not upgraded.
```

after that i tried to check docker activation but it's status active failed yet.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-gardooon-server:~$ sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-09-10 16:29:10 UTC; 4 da>
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 35714 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: docker the client works, but it connecs through a socket to docker the Daemon. The sock file and the docker files used by the Daemon are in /var/lib. Deleting them has made it harder to estimate the state. Files may have been locked because they were in use. Reinstall docker to recreate the files needed (apt --reinstall install docker) use force if you have to and if the service doesn't come up, check the service jounal

Comment: I reinstalled the docker by command (apt --reinstall install docker) according to your comment. but the problem not solved.

Answer (score 0):

I install the docker again completely and then the problem was solved.
but all images and containers are removed.